# Adding ObjectiveFlickr to Project

Tags: xcode, xcode4, armv7, armv6, objectiveflickr

I'm trying to add the ObjectiveFlickr framework to my project.

I tried to follow these instructions:

> ```
> Add ObjectiveFlickr.xcodeproj to your Mac project (from Xcode menu Project > Add to Project...)
> On your app target, open the info window (using Get Info on the target), then in the General tab, add ObjectiveFlickr (library) to Direct Dependencies
> Also, in the same window, add CFNetwork.framework to Linked Libraries
> Drag libObjecitveFlickr.a to the target's Linked Binary With Libraries group
> ```

```
Open the Info window of your target again. Set Configuration to All Configurations, then in the Header Search Paths property, add these two paths, separately (<OF root> is where you checked out ObjectiveFlickr):

<OF root>/Source
<OF root>/LFWebAPIKit   

Use #import "ObjectiveFlickr.h" in your project
```

But, it seems these instructions were written for older versions of XCode (I use 4.6).
I tried to "translate" these instructions to the newer version of XCode, but no matter what i do, libObjectiveFlickr.a stays in red and I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[LFSiteReachability stopChecking] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[LFSiteReachability startChecking] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      -[LFSiteReachability networkConnectivityExists] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
      -[LFSiteReachability startChecking] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[LFSiteReachability startChecking] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[LFSiteReachability networkConnectivityExists] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
      -[LFSiteReachability startChecking] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFSiteReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also link your target against `SystemConfiguration.framework`. You can do this in the same way that you linked against `CFNetwork.framework`.